# Data schema to represent relationship of single column to multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I would like to design a database schema to have the following relationship between tables:

- users
- admins

users and admins have id, email, creator, updater.

Relationship that needs to be addressed are:

- admins can create and update admin
- user can create and update user
- admin can create and update user

How do I represent this in the PostgreSQL database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does ‚user‘ in ‚user can create...‘ refer to a database role?

Comment: Can a "user" be an "admin" as well?

Comment: These are not relationships, these are business logic rules. Based on your current description, it make more sense to have both users and admins in the same table, only add a column for a user type.

Comment: yes, it makes sense to have users and admins to be in the same table. Thank you all for making that clear to me. But how will represent have who created whom logic implemented to populate in creator and updater? My requirement will have a user creates himself, so how can I represent that.

Comment: So you are talking about application users and you will need logic on the application side to handle that.

Comment: @clamp No not on the application side. I just need to know ways to map the creator/updater of a user to another user who is on the same table. As well as when a user creates by himself how will mapping be?. Say one to one relation to the same table or by keeping the id of a creator/updater in the column and fetching it by another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single table, users with a boolean value indicating whether the user is on is not an administrator. The creating user and updating user in the same table and as foreign keys to user_id.

```
create table users
     ( user_id    text
     , user_name  text
     , is_admin   boolean
     , created_by text
     , updated_by text
     , constraint users_pk primary key (user_id)
     , constraint created_fk foreign key (created_by)
                  references users(user_id)
     , constraint updated_fk foreign key (updated_by)
                  references users(user_id) 
     );
```